# Disintegration measures and differential forms

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, measure-theory, smooth-manifolds

Let $X$ and $Y$ be smooth oriented manifolds of dimension $m$ and $n$, and let $f\colon X\to Y$ a proper smooth map.  There is a theorem called the "[Disintegration Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disintegration_theorem)" which says roughly that a measure on $X$ induces a measure on the fibers of $f$ (except for a set of measure 0) such that integrating over fibers and then over $Y$ is the same as integrating over $X$.

Now, since $X$ is a smooth manifold, most measures that anyone would care about are given by $m$-forms $\Omega$, so disintegration of such a measure would hopefully give us $n-m$-forms on the regular fibers of $f$.

In fact, I sort of see how one would define this: the pushforward of $\Omega$ to $Y$ is a top form there, and there is a dual $m$-vector field on $Y$ that pairs to 1 with this top form (maybe with some singularities at non-regular fibers).
At any regular point in $X$, we can choose a subspace in $T_xX$ which maps isomorphically to $T_{f(x)}Y$, and transfer the $m$-vector field to this subspace, and contract with $\Omega$ and pull back to $f^{-1}(f(x))$.  This should be uniquely defined because the components where you've contracted with vectors parallel to the fiber drop out when you do the pull-back.

I don't especially like this phrasing, since it is quite non-canonical, but I'm confident it must work because the disintegration theorem is true.

> I have to imagine that I am not the first person to have had this thought.  Is there some better way of describing this process and making computations with it?  There should be a text book or something that covers this, but I cannot find it.  Anyone have suggestions?

Comment: The Fubini theorem for differential forms is well known. I think it appears in Demailly's Complex Analytic and Differential Geometry. Sometimes called the coarea formula,especially in Riemannian geometry.

Comment: @BenMcKay I appreciate having the keyword of "coarea formula."  That might be enough to solve my problem by Googling.  Telling me this is Fubini's theorem is not very helpful.

Comment: The pushforward operation isn't defined on differential forms, I'm not sure what you mean by the pushforward of $\Omega$ is a top form.

Comment: @JoshLackman Not sure what point you're trying to make.  You don't believe that partial integration is a thing?  Of course, there are issues, but around regular points of the map, pushforward is easy to define.

Comment: I was just stating that I don't what the pushforward of a form is, but I'm assuming it only makes sense for compactly supported ones (or something similar). This seems relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1435998/push-forward-of-differential-form-integration-over-fiber

Comment: @JoshLackman As discussed the answer below, you don't need compact support, you need the map to be proper on the support of $f$ (which is a kind of relative compact support), which is automatic since my map is proper.  Of course, otherwise you would have issues with the integral not converging on the fiber.

Comment: Right, this is discussed in the thread I linked to as well.

Answer (score 7):

You take a top form $\omega_X$ on $X$, so that $f$ is proper on its support, and then there is a pushforward $\omega_Y:=f_*\omega_X$, uniquely defined by $\int_X f^*h\omega_X=\int_Y h\omega_Y$ for any compactly supported function $h$. Try to solve $\omega_X=\xi\wedge f^*\omega_Y$; near regular points $\xi$ is uniquely defined up to adding forms which vanish on the fibers (and we can see this pointwise, using linear algebra and the implicit function theorem) so $\xi$ defines a section of the relative differential form bundle (i.e. the vector bundle whose fiber at each $x\in X$ is $$\Lambda^f_x:=\Lambda^* T^*_x X/\left<f^*T^*_{f(x)}Y\right>$$ hence a differential form on each fiber.

A textbook account of pushforward of forms is in Chapter 30 of my **[Lecture Notes on Differential Geometry](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E6aitHTpaYDXZSxBE12qF8EmoqkbsZnw/view?usp=sharing)**. Also see Demailly, **[Complex Analytic and Differential Geometry](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/%7Edemailly/manuscripts/agbook.pdf)** p. 17.

Comment: When I try to download your lectures-on-differential-geometry.pdf, I get the following  Error Page:

Sun Feb 04 19:18:08 UTC 2024
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
An internal read or write operation failed

Comment: @AntonPetrunin: my university's archive system seems to have crashed entirely. Thanks for pointing this out. I will give another link.